# R: Extracting values from list of model summaries using pattern matching

Tags: r, regex, sapply

I have a list of model summaries (let's say it is a linear model; but this could apply to any model summary).

Currently, I am extracting a certain coefficient from this list of summaries using the following:

```
coef <- sapply(modelsummaries, function(x) x[[4]][[4,1]])
```

How could I do this by calling the variable name instead of relying on row position?

For each of the model summaries within the list, only one variable differs, which is named as V_01, V_02, V_03 etc. This is the variable coefficient I would like to extract.

I was thinking of using the grep function, something like:

```
coef <- sapply(modelsummaries, function(x) x[[4]][[grep("^[V]"),1]])
```

...but haven't got it working. Any suggestions?

Here's a reproducible example (only the last line needs to be tweaked):

```
newdata <- as.data.frame(seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1))
newdata <- as.data.frame(t(newdata))
colnames(newdata) = newdata[1, ]
colnames(newdata) <- paste("V", colnames(newdata), sep = "_")

mtcars <- mtcars
mtcarsmodel <- data.frame(mtcars, newdata)

mtcarsmodel[c(12:20)] <- sample(1:100, 288, replace=TRUE)

xnam <- paste(colnames(mtcarsmodel)[c(4:5)], sep="")
xnam2 <- paste(colnames(mtcarsmodel)[c(12:20)], sep="") 

fmla <- paste(xnam, collapse= "+")
fmla2 <- paste(paste(fmla), "+")
fla <- paste("mpg ~", paste(fmla2))

models <- lapply(setNames(xnam2, xnam2), function(var) {
  form = paste(fla, var)
  lm(form, data=mtcarsmodel)
})

modelsummaries <-lapply(models, summary)
coef <- sapply(modelsummaries, function(x) x[[4]][[4,1]])
```

Comment: `[[` only allows for selection of one element at a time. If your grep leads to a single col, you can use `grep(pattern, names(x[[10]]))` to get the number. See `?grep`, `?names`, `?\`[[\``, etc.

Comment: Best to whip up an example that models the structure of your results.

Comment: Attached an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close, you just needed to tell `grep` what to search on, which is the rownames of the coefficient matrix returned by `coef()` (which is a better way to get them than `[[4]]`). Also so as not to reuse that name, I suggest saving the result in something different, like `coefs`.

```
coefs <- sapply(modelsummaries, function(x) {
  coef(x)[grep("^V", rownames(coef(x))),"Estimate"]
})
       V_0.1        V_0.2        V_0.3        V_0.4        V_0.5        V_0.6        V_0.7        V_0.8 
 0.030927774 -0.053437459  0.009335911 -0.011009187 -0.010303494 -0.001705420 -0.036297492  0.021838044 
       V_0.9 
 0.005457086
```

Also, check out the new `broom` package which can make it easier to extract certain information from models in a tidy way.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with a grep solution, I committed blasphemy and used an sql solution instead:

```
library('sqldf')
new <- lapply(modelsummaries, function(x) setDT(data.frame(x[[4]]), keep.rownames = TRUE)[])
values <- sapply(new, function(x) sqldf("SELECT x.estimate, x.'Pr...t..' FROM x WHERE rn like '%V_%'"))
data <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(values)))
```

I've also come up with a (somewhat ugly) grep based solution:

```
coef <- sapply(modelsummaries, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(grep("^V_", capture.output(x), value = TRUE), "\\s+"))[[2]]))
```